# How to present a Modal View over a Tab Bar Application?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, modalviewcontroller

I'm relatively new to iPhone programming but have read my way through a hefty book already.

I want to build a Tabbed Application where in one of the tabs I can push a button that presents a modal view over the screen.

I have built demo apps that utilize UITabBarController and the ModalView system, but I can't figure out how to combine them.

Help is greatly appreciated.  I'm really stuck because it's this set up of the views that's the only thing I don't know how to do with my app.  If you could give me a rundown (sample code) of how the setup should look, that would be fantastic.

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show a display a modal view controller from one of the tabs of your tab bar controller using the following code.

```
UIViewController* vc = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES]
```

That will cause the View Controller to be displayed modally over the tab bar.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that goes in IBAction that summons the modal.
Because I'm working with a window-based app that is so far just written to flip through the tabs, I'm not quite sure how the modal/delegate would be set up in the code.  When I've done it before (in a singleview app), I used the AppDelegate, but that didn't work with the tabbed app.

Comment: @Collin a lot of barcode scanning apps dedicate the middle tab bar button to present a modal view. I'd like to achieve the exact same functionality in my app but i'm not sure how. Did you figure out how to get it working?

Comment: @Fulvio I was never trying to present the modal view from hitting the tabbar's button itself so I don't have any specific advice there.  I do know, however, that many apps have fully customized tabbars that only *appear* to be stock UITabBars with some small modification.  I use the ShopSavvy app which looks like a stack tabbar save for a large silver scan button in the middle, and wouldn't be surprised if its entirely custom code.